# How would you render the phrase, "the symbol for the suit of spades in a deck of playing cards" in Russian?

Tags: выражения, существительные

How would you write:

> ## ♠
>
> "This is the symbol for spades in a deck of playing cards"

---

The following is not a very good translation:

> ## ♠
>
> Это символ пики в колоде игральных карт.

Comment: I don't think it's an on-topic question here, but this is a reasonable translation if you put "пики" in quotes. Otherwise you have to put it in the right case, and it would be "пик", because suits are usually used in plural. There are other minor improvements that could be made, but on the basic level it is OK.

Comment: In English, the suits are plural as well: https://osgamers.com/frequently-asked-questions/what-is-the-symbol-for-spades

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to define the symbol, I'd say:

> Это символ масти пик.

Or:

> Это символ пиковой масти.

You don't need to mention the deck of playing cards, as the word "масть" already makes the meaning unambiguous.

Also, you might consider using the word "значок" instead of "символ", especially if you're talking about typesetting symbols (from some font, etc), as opposed to a large painting of this symbol, for instance.

Comment: Abolutely! Now *this* is a response you can sink your teeth into. Great job!

Answer (score -1):

It's hard to say without context. But it is possible to say *"Пики - один из четырех символов в колоде игральных карт".*

That way, you avoid the awkward ambiguity associated with the translation of символ пики (символ пики = symbol of playing cards in the nominative / symbol of weapons in the singular, символ пик = symbol of playing cards in the genitive / symbol of weapons in the plural).

Comment: I think this is actually about defining the actual symbol ♠ — *that's* the context.

Comment: For English speakers, maybe. I am answering about the translation into Russian, aren't I? The expression символ пики is not very natural for the Russian language, we say карточная масть.

Comment: We're talking about two different things that exist in both languages. The масть is the [1]suit which is represented by the [2]symbol ♠. So the context for the translation is that [2] represents [1]. Two different concepts to be rendered. In your response, instead of translating/rendering this context, you decided to paraphrase it or replace it with a different concept altogether: [1] is [definition].

Comment: Please render it. I don't mind at all.

Comment: It's not for me to render — I'm not Russian. That would be a job for you 

Comment: I can see that you are unemployed.

Comment: How so? My job is editing English.